# How to get the process number in the function when using Pool from multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, threadpool, python-multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to get current process number in my function when multiprocessing using the Pool. Here is the code that i am using to test this:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import itertools

def function(a,b,c):
    print("Value of a: {} Value of b : {} Constant : {}".format(a,b,c))

a = [4,5,6,7,8]
b = [11,12,13,14,15]

pool = Pool(3)
pool.starmap(function, zip(a,b,itertools.repeat(50)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Right now my output for the function looks like this:

```
Value of a: 4 Value of b : 11 Constant : 50
...
```

What i really want is to also get the Current Process number in my function to notify me exactly which Process is running current iteration of function
Something like this:

```
Value of a: 4 Value of b : 11 Constant : 50 Process : 1
Value of a: 5 Value of b : 12 Constant : 50 Process : 2
Value of a: 6 Value of b : 13 Constant : 50 Process : 3
```

I tried using `multiprocessing.current_process().ident`
But it's showing this output:

```
Value of a: 4 Value of b : 11 Constant : 50 Thread : 33084
Value of a: 5 Value of b : 12 Constant : 50 Thread : 33084
Value of a: 6 Value of b : 13 Constant : 50 Thread : 33084
```

Should i use any other method or attribute from multiprocessing to get the current process number?

Comment: Read up on [multiprocessing.Process.pid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20current_process#multiprocessing.Process.pid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`, which is [actually a thread pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20current_process#module-multiprocessing.dummy), not a process pool. So everything is still running in a single process, which means that each thread is going to have the same `ident` value for `multiprocesing.current_process()`. If you intended to use a thread pool, you could use `threading.current_thread().ident` to get a unique ID for each thread.

If you intend to use a process pool, then `multiprocessing.current_process().ident` will work the way you expect once you switch. You could also use `os.getpid()`, which (at least on Linux) returns the same value.

If you want each thread to have a monotonically increasing ID that counts up from 1, you can do that by assigning the identifier yourself when each thread starts up, like this:

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import itertools

def function(a,b,c):
    print("Value of a: {} Value of b : {} Constant : {} ID: {}".format(a,b,c,d.id))

a = [4,5,6,7,8]
b = [11,12,13,14,15]

d = threading.local()
def set_num(counter):
    d.id = next(counter) + 1

pool = Pool(3, initializer=set_num, initargs=(itertools.count(),))

pool.starmap(function, zip(a,b,itertools.repeat(50)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

`itertools.count()` is thread-safe, so it can be used to assign a unique identifier to each thread in the pool when they are initialized. You can then use a `threading.local` object to store the unique ID for each thread.

If you don't care about actually have an integer value, you can just use `threading.current_thread().name`, which will print a string that has an integer suffix, which counts up from 1.

Comment: I just tried importing `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` and used `threading.current_thread().ident` to get the id but i am still getting these numbers (27772,22660) which are clearly not the thread numbers as i am using 3 thread so these numbers should be (1,2 or 3) am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: There is no thread number assigned by Python that counts up from 1.

Comment: @UsamaIlyas If you really want each thread in the pool that counts up from one, you can do that by assigning the ID yourself. I updated my answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: @UsamaIlyas ***numbers should be (1,2 or 3)***: Using [multiprocessing.Process.name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20current_process#multiprocessing.Process.name) will show `Process-N1:N2:…:Nk`

Comment: @stovfl That won't work because he's using threads, not processes. `threading.current_thread().name` would show `Thread-<#>`, where # starts counting up from 1, though.

Comment: @stovfl Thanks! This is exactly the kind of workaround i wanted.